# Asking for proof of convergence for a conditionally convergent series multiplied piecewise by a positive convergent sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $\sum a_n$ be a convergent series in the reals (which may be conditionally convergent).

Let $\{b_n\}$ be a real sequence converging to $B$ as $n\to\infty$, with $\forall n.\  b_n>0$. (EDIT: $B>0$)

I am working with a proof that asserts that it can be shown that $\sum (a_n b_n)$ is convergent. This obviously isn't a standard result (it would be if $\sum a_n$ was absolutely convergent), and I can't arrive at a proof of it. I've tried looking at the partial sums (using the Cauchy criterion) and proceeding by induction on them, but I have had no success.

Is anyone aware of any detailed proof of this?

Comment: You need monotonicity for $b_n$ for the result to hold in full generality

Comment: Thanks, the proof I'm working with doesn't specify monotonicity, but perhaps I can get something similar if I assume it.

Comment: Can you point me at the proof when monotonicity is assumed?

Comment: The result is not true otherwise without other conditions

Comment: Using $b_n-b$ or $b-b_n$ to get a sequence that is monotonically decreasing to zero, the Dirichlet test (eg wikipedia) gives you the result for series with bounded partial sums only - the convergence of the original series is needed if $b$ the limit of $b_n$ is non zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot prove it, since it is false. Suppose, say, that $a_n=\frac{(-1)^n}n$ and that$$b_n=\begin{cases}1+\frac1{\log(n+1)}&\text{ if $n$ is odd}\\1+\frac2{\log(n+1)}&\text{ if $n$ is even}.\end{cases}$$Then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges, each $b_n$ is greater than $0$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n=1$. But $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nb_n$ diverges.

Comment: Thank you for your counter-example, it has made clear I need to add an additional condition that I overlooked - b_n tends to some B where B also is >0. My apologies for not including that, I'll amend the question.

Comment: I've edited my answer. What do you think?

Comment: It looks convincing to me. And kind of obvious, kicking myself for having missed it. I will go back to the source to double check there's nothing about monotonicity in there.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I have been banging my head against this for days, I should have looked for a counter example first!